# SqlServerCentral ripping off your website

Tags: discussion, clone, copyright-infringement

http://ask.sqlservercentral.com is ripping off your content and layouts :-(

Comment: What about this one too? http://asp.net.bigresource.com/Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-with-Dependency-Injection--2xsM11eW2.html

Answer (score 16):

Those **basta**... *hey, [wait a second!](http://stackexchange.com)*

Comment: How come sqlservercentral isn't listed in the directory of sites on that page?

Comment: We need to be able to double upvote certain answers that truly deserve it.

Comment: @Kragen - The directory is an opt-in list. Only a small fraction of sites are included.

Comment: @RobertCartaino May be I'm being dumb but I don't get this answer is Jeff saying they were part of SE or not? From what I can tell it's a definite clone using [AnswerHub](http://www.dzonesoftware.com/products/answerhub-question-answer-software). Admittedly this answer is old did the URL in the answer used to go somewhere that made more sense? As I was looking for an answer I posted this [Answer on A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277017/202529)

Answer (score 13):

**Edit**: [Now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86966/ask-sql-exchange-site), they are using [OSQA](http://osqa.net) site, instead of Stack Exchange

---

#### See

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

in the page source, its a official site

Comment: -1 OUCH!. That link caused my eyes to spin and then burst. The blur on the top left of the page is just evil.