# Is this website one of the Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion, clone

[This website](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/index.html) is somewhat similar to Stack Exchange websites. It has a very similar structure.

But there are some details which differ (the URL structure, no hyperlinks at the bottom of the page, ugly voting hands instead of nice arrows, not speaking of the UI design itself), besides I couldn't find this page in https://stackexchange.com/sites.

I wonder, does it have **anything** to do with Stack Exchange (hope not)? Or is it just a not-so-well-made copy?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50310/sqlservercentral-ripping-off-your-website

Comment: @Rob W, thanks. I've searched for it with a different url: http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/index.html, and got no results, so I thought no one asked about it )))

Comment: Or this: [Stack Overflow clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Comment: Related: *[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177)*

Comment: Thanks for linking the canonical @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not a Stack Exchange website in any way.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

Here a list of [all sites.](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) Looks like just a clone to me..

- [Are there any clones/alternatives for running a Stack Exchange style Q&A site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)